# Angular 2: Use Pipes within Method with Dependency Injection leads to "Invalid Number of Arguments"-Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking for a way to use a custom pipe within my class. The custom pipe itself ( [taken from here, thank you very much](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/inserting-html-via-angular-2-use-of-domsanitizationservice-bypasssecuritytrusthtml/62562) ) has a dependency injected ( the DomSanitizationService ).

```
import { Pipe, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizationService, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe {

    constructor( protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {  }

    public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html':
                return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style':
                return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script':
                return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url':
                return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl':
                return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
        }
    }

}
```

I can use this pipe in my HTML-Template like this:

```
<div [innerHtml]="myHtmlContent | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

But when I want to use the pipe inside my code, e.g.:

```
getMyValue():string {
    return new SavePipe( ).transform( this.myHtmlContent, 'html' );
    //                  ^--- I should put something in here, I know
}
```

I get an error: **Invalid number of Arguments, expected 1 argument**

I know that when calling the new SavePipe(), I should pass the DomSanitizationService as an argument.

How can I do this? Or better: How can I change the Pipe so that it injects the DomSanitizationService on demand?

Comment: `DomSanitizationService` was renamed. What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: 2.0.0-rc.4 in a Ionic 2b11 project

Comment: It was renamed in RC.6 AFAIR to `DomSanitizer`.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a class with `new SomeClass` Angulars DI is not involved and you have to pass all parameters yourself.

You can inject `DomSanitizationService` to the component where you call `new SafePipe()` and then just pass the injected instance.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {}
...
someMethod() {
  new SafePipe(this.sanitizer);
}
```

Comment: OK, this is logic. But in this case, I have a custom class for a location. So when creating a new location with `let l = new Location()`, I have the same problem again, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code of `Location`. Perhaps you can do the same by just injecting it to make DI instantiate it and also pass all dependencies (same as shown in my answer). You can also inject `SafePipe` directly then you don't need to inject it's dependencies individually.